# BigQuery SQL conditional IN

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have been trying to construct a conditional `IN` like below, but this gives me the `scalar subquery produced more than one element` error. How should I approach this type of query instead? The tables are not related.

```
select * from my_table
where my_table.my_col in (
  case
    when 1 = 1
    then (select my_col from my_other_table_1)
    else (select my_col from my_other_table_2) 
  end
)
```

Comment: Could you give your real sql code?

Comment: I've updated the question to look like real code (although I don't see what difference that makes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below-

```
select * from my_table
where my_table.my_col in (
  SELECT
  case
    when 1 = 1 then my_col_1 
    else my_col_2 
  END
  from my_other_table
)
```

As your other tables are not related, you can try this below logic-

```
select * from my_table
where 
(1=1 and my_col IN (select my_col_1 from my_other_table_01)
OR
(3=3 and my_col IN (select my_col_2 from my_other_table_02)
```

Comment: Thanks! But what happens if the subqueries are from different tables? (see update).

Comment: Establish proper relation between tables and apply the same logic.

Comment: The "other tables" are not related to each other.

Comment: Show sample data from all 3 tables and then show your expected output from them.

Comment: @CHRD, please check another logic added.

Comment: I don't think sample data is needed in this case (I prefer keeping the question clean with no unnecessary info). Your updated answer is exactly what I was looking for. Works great. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to see it worked. You can also put an up vote :)